# End to end delay with MM1 queue

Tags: delay

A route of 340 km has 17 hops in between.

Effective bit rate per hop is 16.384 Mb/s and average link utilization is 80%.

The message is 486 bytes of payload and 28 bytes of header.

Velocity is 2 × 10<sup>8</sup> m/s.

How do I find the end to end delay of one packet?

Comment: This question might better suite to network engineering than ee.se?

Comment: @JRE: I know that you do a lot of clean-up edits. I'm not sure if you're aware that Stack Exchange supports HTML entities such as `&deg;`, `&times;`, `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&pm;` (+/-), `&ge;` (>=), etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` (superscript) and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts but they don't render in the comments.

Comment: Not used the HTML code as much.. \$\deg \times \Omega \mu \pm \ge e^y R_x\$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
         _______
TX  ____|message|_______________________
                          _______
RX  _____________________|message|______
        <---------------->           (a)
     or <------------------------>   (b)
```

Where does the delay end? At (a) or (b).

Update your question with your thoughts and calculations for the rest of the question.

Comment: the route is 340km from source to destination with 17 hops/links. Assuming an MM1 queue I am trying to calculate the transmission + propagation + queuing + processing delay. I got 26ms for final answer but not sure

Comment: OK, so edit your question and show your calculations. I haven't done the calculations yet. You didn't answer my hint question.